# Change VB project code to C# using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know how to Change VB project code to C# using Visual Studio 2010?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe Visual Studio itself provides any capabilities around this, but there are various other options. There are specific converters such as the ones from [Tangible](http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/). Alternatively, you could build the VB code and then decompile to C# in something like [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) or [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). (Latest versions of Reflector are not free, but there is still a [version 6 release which will not have a time bomb](http://eon.businesswire.com/news/eon/20110426007021/en/.NET-Reflector/Reflector/Red-Gate).)

Note that a verbatim translation of the code is likely to end up calling various methods in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly - you'll want to do a bit more work to turn it into idiomatic C#.

Answer (score 3):

Directly in Visual Studio you can't do this. However, you can use tools such as [this one](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) or [this one](http://www.dotnetspider.com/convert/Vb-To-Csharp.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Telerik has a free converter [here](http://converter.telerik.com/)